# Pandas data-frame ungrouping functionality

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 7.5, 10], [2, 5, 1, 3]]).T
df1.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df1

   col1  col2  col3
0     2   2.0     2
1     2   5.0     5
2     5   7.5     1
3     7  10.0     3
```

Now I want to ungroup the 3rd column and get a longer dataframe with a new column col4, as shown below in df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7], [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7.5, 10, 10, 10], [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3]]).T

df2.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

df2

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0      2   2.0     2     1
1      2   2.0     2     2
2      2   5.0     5     1
3      2   5.0     5     2
4      2   5.0     5     3
5      2   5.0     5     4
6      2   5.0     5     5
7      5   7.5     1     1
8      7  10.0     3     1
9      7  10.0     3     2
10     7  10.0     3     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to use `groupby` with `reindex`.

```
# custom apply function
def func(group):
    return group.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(np.arange(group.col3)).fillna(method='ffill')
# groupby apply
result = df1.groupby(level=0).apply(func)


     col1  col2  col3
0 0     2   2.0     2
  1     2   2.0     2
1 0     2   5.0     5
  1     2   5.0     5
  2     2   5.0     5
  3     2   5.0     5
  4     2   5.0     5
2 0     5   7.5     1
3 0     7  10.0     3
  1     7  10.0     3
  2     7  10.0     3


result['col4'] = result.index.get_level_values(1) + 1
result.reset_index(drop=True)


    col1  col2  col3  col4
0      2   2.0     2     1
1      2   2.0     2     2
2      2   5.0     5     1
3      2   5.0     5     2
4      2   5.0     5     3
5      2   5.0     5     4
6      2   5.0     5     5
7      5   7.5     1     1
8      7  10.0     3     1
9      7  10.0     3     2
10     7  10.0     3     3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps.
I have one more question:
result.reset_index(drop=True) removes the first indexed column, but I am trying to remove the next column of row numbers: 0,1,2,3 etc
and doing reset_index(drop=True) again does not seem to remove it. Can you tell me how to take this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy for faster calculation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 7.5, 10], [2, 5, 1, 3]]).T
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

x = df.values
n = df.iloc[:,-1].astype(int).values

data = np.repeat(x,n,axis=0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.loc[:,3] = n.repeat(n)
df1.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

print(df1)
```

Gives:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4
0    2.0   2.0   2.0     2
1    2.0   2.0   2.0     2
2    2.0   5.0   5.0     5
3    2.0   5.0   5.0     5
4    2.0   5.0   5.0     5
5    2.0   5.0   5.0     5
6    2.0   5.0   5.0     5
7    5.0   7.5   1.0     1
8    7.0  10.0   3.0     3
9    7.0  10.0   3.0     3
10   7.0  10.0   3.0     3
```